# Preserving file extension in WinHTTrack

Tags: httrack

I seem unable to find the option to preserve file extensions when copying a site using WinHTTrack (i.e. index.aspx is renamed to index.html).

Is this possible? Google turns up nothing.

Comment: I would like to know too, or eventually the name of an alternate software to do the same task.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to FTP into the server as an authorized user in order to obtain server-side scripts and other objects not referenced by any HTML files. The 'why' is too complicated to explain. Here is one FAQ from HTTRACK's FAQ [page](https://www.httrack.com/html/faq.html#QM1) that answers your question:

> Q: How can I retrieve .asp or .cgi sources instead of .html result?
>
> A: You can't! For security reasons, web servers do not allow that.